# R code to open command windows to run a secondary script

Tags: r, cmd, command

In 2018, I used the script below and it was running successfully. Now, in 2024, it's not running and I cannot find out why. All functions seems to be the same. I am running it on a different computer though (as admin)

I have a main R process running, and when it meets a certain criteria, it needs to start a follow-up script (with some parameters obtained from the main process). I can have multiple independent follow-up scrips running off my main process.

The code below is supposed to start the follow-up scripts:

1. Define a new file name (to sink in some results)
2. Opens a new CMD window, and runs an R-script and feeds in some additional parameters. The R script writes a txt file and adds data every few seconds, and I use
3. PowerShell to open a CMD window that shows the last rows (tails) of the text file (so can view the last rows, while recording all historical data)

The parts I really need to run is the system() part. RScript is in my PATH, so RScript can run succesfully in the CMD line

```
file.name     <- paste0("C:/dir/TestFile", gsub(" |:|-", "_",Sys.time()), "_", ".txt")

  system("cmd.exe", 
         input = paste("RScript  C:/dir/some R script.R", 
                       parameter1, 
                       parameter2,
                       parameter3
                       ">",
                       file.name), 
         wait = FALSE, 
         show.output.on.console = FALSE) 
  
  
  cat(input = paste('\n\npowershell -command "& {Get-Content ',file.name, '  -wait}"\n\n'))  # Put this in the CMD line to get a document that tails the txt-file
```

I'm not sure how to start trouble shooting...
When I run the code, the R console simply returns a '0'...

EDIT: the last line 'cat(input...' creates a line of text I can copy to then paste into a CMD prompt.

Comment: 1) Instead of `system` it is recommended the use of `system2`: 2) `cat` doesn't put the command in the CMD line, once again, use `system2`.